# Uso de "con" para una cantidad arbitraria de elementos

Tags: uso-de-palabras, preposiciones, sintaxis

Esto suena bien:

> Café con leche con pan con manteca

Pero esto suena incorrecto:

> Café con leche **con** pan

Del mismo modo, esto suena bien:

> Café con leche con pan con manteca y mermelada

Pero esto incorrecto:

> Café con leche y pan con manteca **con** mermelada

En los dos casos que suenan incorrectos, ¿se puede usar ese ultimo "con"?

Comment: Mejor alternar con un "y": café con leche y pan con manteca, café con leche y pan con manteca y mermelada.

Comment: @Gustavson entiendo, más que nada la pregunta va a si hay reglas que aplican al "con" y no a la "y".

Comment: Más que reglas, lo que prevalece es el sentido comùn de no repetir innecesariamente una preposición hasta el hartazgo. Es una cuestión estilística más que gramatical.

Comment: @Gustavson Cuando está escrito se vé redundante y "extraño", pero hablado es más inteligible en mi experiencia, al menos los que puse que se escuchan bien.

Comment: Qué bien irían los paréntesis para resolver estas ambigüedades :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya se dijo en los comentarios, la decisión es estilística, no de gramática.

En las enumeraciones usando *y* se suele considerar erróneo repetir, y por eso decimos *naranjas, manzanas, peras y bananas*, en vez de *naranjas y manzanas y peras y bananas*. Repetir *y* no es incorrecto, sin embargo, y es posible si se quiere dar énfasis, lo cual es un recurso común en poesía: se llama [polisíndeton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polis%C3%ADndeton).

Se puede hacer polisíndeton con *con*, pero en casos como los ejemplificados el problema es que no estamos haciendo una enumeración simple sino usando *con* para agrupar frases que a su vez están unidas por esta misma conjunción: *pan con manteca*, *café con leche*.

Lo que hacemos los hablantes para evitar la cacofonía en estos casos es:

1. Agrupar prosódicamente, es decir, con el ritmo del habla, los pares de palabras que deben estar más asociados, como *café con leche* y *pan con manteca*,¹ y separarlos entre sí un poco con una pausa: *café-con-leche... con... pan-con-manteca*. Esto es el equivalente prosódico de "agrupar con paréntesis" como en matemáticas.
2. Cuando es posible, transformar *con* en *y*: *café-con-leche... con... pan-con-manteca-y-mermelada*, sin dejar de usar la prosodia para agrupar los items que estén más relacionados entre sí.

¹ En particular *café con leche* y *pan con manteca* ya están tan asociados que suelen pronunciarse y tratarse como una sola palabra (yo oigo muy seguido a parejas en bares pedir *“dos cafeconleches”*).

Comment: No estoy totalmente de acuerdo en que el empleo de múltiples "y" sea "erroneo": Puede emplearse para resaltar aún más la variedad o el tedio que produce algo, por señalar dos ejemplos rápidos. "Y una vez y otra y otra y otra ..." es una frase perféctamente válida, al igual que la que empleas de las frutas.

Comment: @RubioRic Es cierto. Acabo de editar y ampliar la respuesta para corregir eso.